# Difference Between **/target vs /target in docker ignore

Tags: docker

I Have two docker ignore files inside my project. One container /target and other contains **/target.

.dockerignore file is used to excluded when building a Docker image. Is there any difference between these two

What is the difference between */target vs /target in docker ignore

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) `**/target`, with the `**` wildcard, matches all target files in any subdirectories including zero. So `target`, `foo/target` or `foo/bar/target` will be excluded.

> Docker also supports a special wildcard string ** that matches any number of directories (including zero). For example, **/*.go will exclude all files that end with .go that are found in all directories, including the root of the build context.

whereas `*/target` will match only direct subdirectories and `target` without wildcards will only match the single `target` file in the concerned directory.